# explicit deep link navigation backstack issue

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, explicit, deeplink

Lets take an app with 2 activities MainActivity and Activity2. MainAct is the launcher activity. 
Activity2 contains a default navhost fragment having a navgraph with two fragments, fragment1(start-destination), fragment2.

When starting MainActivity I create a notification having a content intent created with NavDeepLinkBuilder that navigates to Activity2.fragment2.
The problem appears if MainActivity is running and active in the foreground and Activity2.fragment2 is navigated then after I press back it does not navigate back to MainActivity as it should but instead it takes me to launcher home screen.

I also tested this behaviour with implicit deep links:
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d http://fragment2/
Having MainActivity open  Activity2 gets on top and on back press it navigates to MainActivity as it should.

I think either I did not construct the explicit link correctly or this is a bug with explicit deep links.
Complete demo project https://github.com/iulian0512/navtest

TLDR:

Explicit Deep Link (invoked from notification)

MainActivity(already running) -> Activity2 (back press) -> Launcher home screen

Implicit Deep Link (invoked from terminal)

MainActivity(already running) -> Activity2 (back press) -> MainActivity

LE: I created a video to try to explain the issue more concisely https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBShKSjOcL8

Comment: i filled an issue on their tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142379671